# jQuery datepicker not working -> what steps to perform?

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker

I am working on a project, that has several NuGet clientside scripting (bootstrap ect..) packages installed.

Somewhere along the line I updated packages and made some changes etc...
Now datepicker is not functioning any more. See screenshot.

[image: jQuery datepicker not functioning]

Here is my inputfield:

```
<input class="form-control end-of-bookyear valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field End of book year must be a date." id="EndOfBookYear" name="EndOfBookYear" type="text" value="" aria-describedby="EndOfBookYear-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

And the div that should hold the datepicker:

```
<div id="mceu_123" class="mce-widget mce-tooltip mce-tooltip-n" role="presentation" style="left: 441.328px; top: 383px; z-index: 131070; display: none;"><div class="mce-tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="mce-tooltip-inner">Print</div></div>
```

I am pretty sure it is a jQuery CSS issue.

**Where do I even start to resolve this problem?**

I will share some content to show you my situation. I am close to desperate!
**Please help me solve this puzzle, or at least tell me where to start solving this puzzle.**

Here is my bundleconfig:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/moment.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/daterangepicker").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/daterangepicker.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/site").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/Site.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/Gridmvc.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/datepicker.min.css",
                  "~/Content/daterangepicker-bs3.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

And my BootstrapEditorTemplatesConfig:

```
public class BootstrapEditorTemplatesConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles()
    {
        BundleCollection bundles = BundleTable.Bundles;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/val").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/validation.js"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap*",
                    //"~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js",
                    "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
                    //"~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture." + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString() + ".js",                        
                    "~/Scripts/filebutton.js"
                    //"~/Scripts/globalize-datepicker.js"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/md").Include(
            "~/Scripts/MarkdownDeepLib.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/markdown.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/site").Include(
             "~/Content/themes/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"));

        // By default it will exclude the MarkdownDeepLib.min.js file because of its .min.js extension.
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
        // BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

This is the *Head* section from my _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Query Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
    @Html.Partial("Variables", variablesVm)
</head>
```

This is in the end of the body of my _Layout.cshtml:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/val") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/md")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/daterangepicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <!-- TinyMCE -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        height: @tinyMceDefaultHeight,
        image_advtab: true,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink autosave lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
        ],
        resize: false,
        selector: "textarea#BackgroundInfo,textarea#Question,textarea#OwnTeamAnalysis,textarea#Answer,textarea#ImplementationExplanation,textarea#Text",
        statusbar: false,
        theme: "modern",
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor",
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is my scriptsfolder:
[image: scriptsfolder]

Here is my content folder:
[image]

I also had to remove code from validation.js
As it uses: Globalize.culture, which is not a function of the new Globalize after updating the nuGet packages.

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.9.1.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery.globalize/globalize.js" />
/// <reference path="../moment.js" />


$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    }
});

//$(function () {
//    /* initialize globalization, for parsing dates and decimals */
//    var data = $("html").attr("lang") || $("meta[http-equiv='content-language']").attr("content") || "en-US";
//    Globalize.culture(data);

//    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
//        return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
//    }

//    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
//        return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseDate(value));
//    }
//    //moment.lang(data, {
//    //    days: Globalize.culture().calendar.days.names,
//    //    daysShort: Globalize.culture().calendar.days.namesAbbr,
//    //    daysMin: Globalize.culture().calendar.days.namesShort,
//    //    months: Globalize.culture().calendar.months.names,
//    //    monthsShort: Globalize.culture().calendar.months.namesAbbr
//    //});
//});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @ADyson: none. No errors shown.

Comment: where is the code that actually attaches the datepicker to that field? Is it definitely running?

Comment: ...assuming that it is, then: there's so much CSS stuff here it's going to be difficult to pinpoint just by looking at it. If you inspect the relevant elements using the Chrome dev tools and look at computed styles you might be able to see where the CSS rules are coming from and find something that's causing the picker to be hidden. Next, if you know what changes were made, then roll them back one by one until it works again. If you don't, remove CSS references from the bundles one by one until you find the culprit. Trial and error is probably the only way, sadly.

Comment: ![This is a screenshot of my breakpoint](http://i63.tinypic.com/2s8mnpw.png).

Comment: ok. so you are using bootstrap-datepicker, not jquery datepicker. big difference!

Comment: your scripts, bundles etc seems to include code for about 3 different datepickers. Think your solution needs a bit of a clean-up

Comment: I fully agree with you! There is too much clienside code going on. I was put on this project, I am a C# backend developer. I did not add this stuff. But I am the one who needs to fix it. Where should I start deleting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129808/discussion-between-tony-kilopapamikegolf-and-adyson).

Comment: depends which components are actually being used throughout the code - I can't see the rest of it so I don't know. If you have multiple things like datepickers, standardise on one and remove all references to the others. It's a massive pain in the backside. People have just added whatever they felt like and eventually it's caused enough of a mess to break things and make it hard to see the wood for the trees. I suspect lack of technical oversight and a culture of cut+paste code from the net without understanding it. Sadly I suspect this won't be the last issue you find

Comment: But I can't really help other than to suggest you inspect that one control using the dev tools to see if you can pinpoint and make a workaround for that one issue, or you pare everything back to the bare bones and see what breaks, then build it back up again in a less insane way.

Comment: Basically, could I setup an 'empty HTML' page and see what happens when moving script and CSS around? Trial & Error , see what happens.

Comment: that might help, add in the components one by one until the datepicker breaks. But then if you remove a component to fix the datepicker you have to make sure it doesn't break something elsewhere in the project.

Comment: I also removed some code from validation.js , let me add it to my question.

Comment: removing some validation JS would cause not the datepicker to break, they aren't related at all.

Comment: My conclusion: bootstrap and jQuery don't mix well. I will remove bootstrap datepicker and replace it by jQuery.

Comment: they can work ok together, but given that bootstrap datepicker is an add-on to the main bootstrap framework, and you've already got jquery UI included, which provides a datepicker plus several other useful widgets, I'd agree that's a good policy.

Comment: @ ADyson: I choose not to remove anything, instead replace datepicker functionality by: [Zebra Datepicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/)

Comment: I was finally able to finish this misery, by just adding another datepicker, the Zebra Datepicker as described. I had nor the time, nor the mood, to dig myself a hole to try to remove stuff. And the application is once again functional, so it works.